# How to add the value of two counter in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to count the number of times two buttons are clicked but at the same time, I want to know how many times each of them is clicked too.

```
<div id="app">
    <p><button v-on:click="counter1 += 1">Add One More Click</button></p>
    <p><button v-on:click="counter2 += 1">Add One More Click</button></p>
    <p>The buttons have been clicked {{ counter1+counter2 }} times</p>
    <p>The button 1 has been clicked {{ counter1 }} times</p>
    <p>The button 2 has been clicked {{ counter2 }} times</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            counter: 0,
            button1: 0,
            button2: 0
        }
    })
</script>
```

I would appreciate it if someone can let me know how is this done using vue?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you are incremented `counter1` and `counter2` but they are not defined in your code. You have `button1` and `button2` instead. If you align the names and fix the incorrectly named variables it will work.

Personally, though, I would use a `computed` property to be used instead of adding `counter1` and `counter2` in the template.

See proof-of-concept example here:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter1: 0,
    counter2: 0
  },
  computed: {
    totalClicks() {
        return this.counter1 + this.counter2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p><button v-on:click="counter1++">Add One More Click</button></p>
  <p><button v-on:click="counter2++">Add One More Click</button></p>
  <p>The buttons have been clicked {{ totalClicks }} times</p>
  <p>The button 1 has been clicked {{ counter1 }} times</p>
  <p>The button 2 has been clicked {{ counter2 }} times</p>
</div>
```